How to insert an image into a rectangle in Tkinter
I can't figure out how to insert an image into a rectangle. I'm using TKinter.
I have a long rectangle and I want to insert an image into the left corner, but how?
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

#root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 1)
root.geometry("300x2000")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


head = Canvas(bg="orange", width=1000, height=1000)
head.pack(anchor=NW, expand=1)
im = PhotoImage(file="top.png", width=100, height=100)
label = ttk.Label( image=im, anchor= NW)
head.create_image(1,1 , anchor=NW, image=im)


root.mainloop()

The picture appears cropped

By "rectangle" do you mean that you want to add the image to a Label? Or are you wanting to draw a canvas rectangle object around an image?

Why do you create a canvas of size 1000x1000 inside a window of size 300x2000? The width of the canvas is larger than that of the window.

The cropping is because you set the width and height options when creating instance of PhotoImage().

you don't need Label if you use create_image

Edit:


@kekret made this comment.


The canvas should have been 1000 by 100, and the photograph itself was very small. but she doesn't appear




I have a long rectangle and I want to insert an image into the left  corner, but how? And the picture appears cropped.


The problem can be fixed.
Change index value:
im = PhotoImage(file="top.png", width=100, height=100)

Change this from 1000 to 400 because you are adding another Label's widget. So, you can see widgets.
im = PhotoImage(file="top.png", width=400, height=400)


Move head.pack(fill='both',anchor=NW, expand=1)  before
root.mainloop().
You are missing Label Layout Manager such as pack(), grid(), or place()`. That is why you cannot see the label's widget.
I add background='red' for Label widget. So you can where it is.

Snippet re-modified:
head = Canvas(root, bg="orange", width=1000, height=100)
#head.pack(fill='both',anchor=NW, expand=1)  #<== comment out
im = PhotoImage(file="p2.png", width=400, height=400)
label = ttk.Label(root, image=im, anchor= NW, background='red')
label.pack(pady=10)  #<== Add this
head.create_image(1,1 , anchor=NW, image=im)  #<== Add this
head.pack(fill='both',anchor=NW, expand=1)

Screenshot: You can see all widgets:


1oh sorry, I forgot to change the value. The canvas should have been 1000 by 100, and the photograph itself was very small. but she doesn't appear...
